# How to Add or customize product information for add product?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, products, forms

How to customize or adding product information in the add product form.

Comment: you to add the tab in the product like description , review

Comment: No i want to add information in the form like After Sku add name of the state

Comment: you add attribute in the CATALOG -> ATTRIBUTES

Comment: No I want add only information in the admin panel

Comment: Can i add information after SKU in add product?

Comment: like that description of the product

Comment: yes i want to add custom tab related to this?

Comment: you need to make it display as "information" next to description tab in product detail page for each and every product.

Comment: Yes i want to add custom tab using information of product and add in admin section

Comment: http://blog.landofcoder.com/add-custom-tab-product-page-magento2/

Comment: you try this link